# Android dealing with database versions regarding updates

Tags: android, database, sqlite, upgrade

Is there any documentation on how to best deal with database upgrades in android?

I am developing an application and have been testing it on my own telephone. All works fine, over the past few deploys I had to add some columns to my table and due to upgrade statements that are executed if the old database version is lesser then a certain database version.

However when I try to run the application on another phone, that gives errors due to the fact that there is no previous version and thus the column isn't added.

Is there any best practice or documentation on how to handle database upgrading and versioning? I tried googling around for specific questions, but much good didn't come out of that.

Here's the relevant code I am using at the moment:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 11;

private static class LocalLoginDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    LocalLoginDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(TAG,DATABASE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if(oldVersion < 11) {
            Log.d(TAG + "Upgrade",DATABASE_ALTER);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any documentation on how to best deal with database upgrades in android?

Use [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), which will give you control when a schema change is detected, so you can upgrade the database.

---

**UPDATE**

> However when I try to run the application on another phone, that gives errors due to the fact that there is no previous version and thus the column isn't added.

Your `DATABASE_CREATE` needs to have the column as well. For a new install (or after the user does Clear Data on your app), there is no existing database, and so `onCreate()`, not `onUpgrade()`, is called.

Comment: That's what I'm doing already, I'll edit my post with the code

Comment: I did but apparently I made a spelling error in it. Works like a charm now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shameless Plug: I know you have this issue resolved but I am working on an open source set of DSL's that makes it easy to create SqliteOpenHelper/ContentProvider/Contract API and manages upgrades through migrations http://robotoworks.com/mechanoid-plugin/mechanoid-db

Its still very early days and I am busy writing docs however its already useful to anyone working with sqlite in Android and the more people using it will make it better :)